# How can I escape single-quotes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script on my site (http://www.xeasycorex.net) for a Tumblr button in each post. The `strPostTitle.replace` line escapes any double-quotes, but I need to do the same for single-quotes as it's terminating the string when present in post titles and not displaying the button, I'm just not sure how to do this

Thanks!

```
<script>
var strPostUrl = "<data:post.url/>";
var strPostTitle = '<data:post.title/>';
var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
var strNewTitle = strPostTitle.replace(/"/g, '"');
document.write("<a href='http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url="+strNewUrl+"&amp;name="+strNewTitle+"'><img src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Vw74mICSigg/USjO29GAujI/AAAAAAAARHE/dY0nzXtwTVU/s81/tumblr-share.png'/></a>");
</script>
```

Comment: use \' to escape single quotes

Comment: How is `<data:post.url/>` substituted in?

Answer (score 0):

Because the single-quotes is seemed as special character in javascript, that you should use back slash to transfer it.  `\'`
Follow this link to find more about this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp.
I changed you code, so now it doesn't need to escape anything.

```
  <script>
        var strPostUrl = escape('<data:post.url/>');
    var strPostTitle = escape('<data:post.title/>');
    var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
    document.write('<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+strNewUrl+'name="'+strPostTitle+'"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Vw74mICSigg/USjO29GAujI/AAAAAAAARHE/dY0nzXtwTVU/s81/tumblr-share.png"/></a>');
        </script>
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work. I understand what it's trying to achieve but the button doesn't display at all

Comment: If I copy the code as is from the JS fiddle page, I get the following error (from Blogger):
Your template could not be parsed as it is not well-formed. Please make sure that all XML elements are closed properly. <br/> XML error message: Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Error 500

Comment: I'm still using my original code on the site. It just doesn't load when there's a single-quote in the post title. When I use your code nothing seems to load

Comment: You can copy my code and create a new html file, just paste my code into it and open it with IE, can you do this to check what the result is?

Comment: Before I do that, I noticed that the jsFiddle page doesn't seem to finish loading for me. I think you also have an extra " after name=. After removing that, the code parses but nothing loads

Comment: I can't open jsfiddle now too, just ignore it but it's weird that I can't see the button which also contains a + signal while you can't

Comment: I tested the jsFiddle code and it loads, but if I swap the title variable with a string using a ', it doesn't load anymore

Comment: I changed your code to this: var strPostUrl = escape('http://www.google.com');
var strPostTitle = escape('don't');
var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
document.write('<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+strNewUrl+'&amp;name='+strPostTitle+'"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Vw74mICSigg/USjO29GAujI/AAAAAAAARHE/dY0nzXtwTVU/s81/tumblr-share.png"/></a>');
If I take out the ' in the title variable, the button loads, but if I leave it, it doesn't

Comment: <script>
    var strPostUrl = escape('google.com');
    var strPostTitle = escape("don\'t");;
    var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
    document.write('<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+strNewUrl+'name="'+strPostTitle+'"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Vw74mICSigg/USjO29GAujI/AAAAAAAARHE/dY0nzXtwTVU/s81/tumblr-share.png"/></a>');
    </script>

Comment: Try the above code, you kill me. "don't" has a single-quote you should use "don/'t"

Comment: The problem is that I used "don't" as an example, but I actually use "<data:post.title/>", which dynamically fetches the post title, so I can't really use a backslash with that

Comment: OK, got it. You should do the conversion in back end, so in front end, you don't need to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `encodeURIComponent` JavaScript function:

```
var strPostUrl   = encodeUIRComponent("<data:post.url/>");
var strPostTitle = encodeURIComponent("<data:post.title/>");
```

Here is an explanation of the function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The button doesn't load at all